# Display DegreesMinutesSeconds on status bar

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcobjects

I have used status bar to display x and y coordinates in `esriDirectionUnits.esriDUDegreesMinutesSeconds` form.

I have created the code like this

statusBarXY.Text = string.Format("{0}, {1}  {2}", e.mapX, e.mapY, esriDirectionUnits.esriDUDegreesMinutesSeconds);

but it will not display any format like this X=70°0'20.797"E  Y=  22°28'.072" N
                                                      X= 700'20.797"E                                     Y= 2228'.072"N

How could I make this?  If any one has a solution please send me link or a sample.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this [thread](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/41146-set-map-units-or-override-units-to-dms). There is a VBA sample showing you how to set the display format. It looks like you are wanting to combine 2 different display formats, is this correct? You may need to have a play around with the *ICustomNumberFormat* interface but I have not done this, so may be a "red herring"?

Comment: i want only degreeminuteseconds format to show. thanks for your reply..